# Relating Dirac mass with surface integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, differential-geometry, dirac-delta

I know that for a smooth function $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ with $\nabla g(x)\neq 0$, there holds the formula
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\delta(g(x))f(x)\,dx=\int_{g=0}\frac{1}{|\nabla g(x)|}f(x)\,d\sigma(x)$$
where $\,d\sigma$ is the surface measure induced by $[g=0]$ and $\delta$ the one dimensional Dirac mass. I wonder, what is the equivalent expression for $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ for $m<n$, when $Dg(x)\neq 0$? In other words what is the scaling factor in the surface integral to compensate for the $m$-dimensional Dirac mass? Is it something like $|Dg(x)|^m$?

Comment: You need to start by assuming that $Dg(x)$ has rank $m$ for every $x$ with $g(x)=0$. Then $g=0$ will be a submanifold of dimension $n-m$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes for sure, as long as that holds, what is the scaling factor in front of $f$ at the surface integral?

Comment: You will probably want the norm of the $m$-form $dg_1\wedge\dots\wedge dg_m$, which should be the square root of the sum of the squares of the $m\times m$ minors. A good test case should be the function $g(x)=(g_1(x_1),g_2(x_2),\dots,g_m(x_m))$. I'm not writing this as an answer because I haven't thought it through carefully.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful! And I guess this norm has to be raised to the $m$ correct?

Comment: Why? Try the test case.

Comment: You're right, thanks again!